# What server platform to choose for periodically running a standalone (Java) program?

Tags: java

I need to develop a game server that will run periodically (e.g., triggered by a CRON job every five minutes or hour as appropriate). Once started up, the server will access all of the current game state (fetched through REST from the game's data servers (Stackmob, Parse or similar), do the processing of player actions, and then POST the results back to the data server. In other words, it will be doing a lot of HTTP requests, but does not itself necessarily need to be a web service.

I've been considering multiple ways of developing this.

- I do not feel for setting up a server myself, so I need to find a service to run this on that permits the workflow I would like.
- The game engine is Java, so something that works neatly with that.
- Will need to GET and POST data files, so access to static files would be needed.

Most of the services that exist which provide something similar to what I require are directed at web services - which generally means that one needs to jump through some hoops to get things to work.

- Google App Engine, for instance, would require that I implement this using backends (since the game server could potentially run for more than 60 seconds), and isn't particularly happy with the idea of static files.
- Amazon EC2 would seem easier to develop on (again by building a web service frontend, of course), but there seems to be relatively poor support for CRON.

Generally speaking, it feels like I want to shoot some sparrows with a slingshot, but all the services are offering me cannons. Are there any alternative platforms/frameworks  beyond the big two mentioned above that would be suitable for something like this?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. For performance reasons your backend should be very close to your game server (same computer or same local network). Therefore it's not clear why are you talking about cloud services and what;s wrong with unix cron?

Comment: Unix cron is fine, except that you need a UNIX server to run it on. I am not really interested in running and maintaining my own server for something like this.

Comment: Performance-wise, the backend server is running asynchronously with the game data, so being very close is not really a requirement. Practically, the game server provides access to mobile devices, so using something like Stackmob, et al for that is a significantly easier solution than rolling one of my own.

Comment: @VadimGulyakin: He's obviously not talking about a realtime backend. I guess he wants to do things like rankings, generating and applying world events, building indexes, etc. Things where you need a fairly frequent but not realtime recurring task.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Much more succinctly put than I managed to.

Comment: GAE *definitely* supports static files: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/). They support Java. If you created a project that used a [single worker dyno](http://www.heroku.com/pricing#0-1) then the hosting would be free (see link).

The process would be running continuously, so you might want use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) for periodic execution. You could also use Quartz, but it might be overkill.

**Edit:**

Here's some links that might help get started:

- [Running non-web Java processes on Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku)
- [Heroku Java quickstart](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java) - this is for a web app ('web dyno') rather than a 'worker dyno', but it may help.
- [java.herokuapp.com](http://java.herokuapp.com/) has links to some example projects (again web apps rather than workers)

Answer (score 1):

How about using EC2, but rather than putting the scheduler in the instance (which won't work because the instance can go away at any time), putting it in AWS? Like this guy:

http://alestic.com/2011/11/ec2-schedule-instance

Alternatively, if you manage your EC2 instances through Ylastic, it looks even easier:

http://blog.ylastic.com/scheduling-tasks-on-the-aws-cloud

Although you'll have to pay for Ylastic as well as EC2, i imagine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nifty way of writing something like this in Groovy with Maven. You can write a multithreaded Groovy script to pull the stats, do the updates, etc. and then have maven's assembly plugin assemble the whole thing into a self-contained, executable jar file that can be called by a CRON job. One nice thing about Groovy is that its syntax allows you to do this:

```
def google = "http://google.com".toURL().text
```

which will turn the string into a URL and handle all of the details of turning the URL into a HTTPURLConnection and getting the raw text.

Answer (score 0):

You could develop the app as a standalone Java program first and then worry about where to deploy it later.

To develop the app you could write a simple Java program that uses HtmlUnit to talk to the external web services. The job could be internally started via Quartz. If you really wanted to start the job externally via CRON, you could have CRON run the app, passing in args. The app would then run and exit.

Alternatively, you could have the app always running and have cron run a bash script that triggers the job in some way.

Essentially, all you need to deploy is a Unix machine so you could use AWS.